# JavaScript-only file upload on web page

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

Am I correct in understanding that it's impossible for the UI (i.e. through JavaScript alone) to know the progress of an  upload as it's being POSTed, without using Flash or HTML5's XMLHttpRequest Level 2 specification?

Comment: I'll leave it open to somebody who can provide information and details with their Answer. :)

Comment: I don't see the question. You're correct. And...?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct. For information about using HTML5 to monitor progress, see:

1. http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/
2. http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#xmlhttprequestupload

For information about using Flash, see:

1. SWFUploader @ http://swfupload.org/project (popular solution)
2. jQuery "Uploadify" plugin using SWFUploader: http://www.uploadify.com
3. Other options: http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=flash+file+uploader&aq=f&aqi=g4g-m1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=ae3fa2fab1e0dd34

Answer (score 1):

There are alternatives, but they're obviously not as precise: poll the server (in a parallel request) for upload progress. JsUpload does this, for instance: http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/#How_does_it_work.

Oh, and of course, there's also Gears, Silverlight and BrowserPlus, as alternatives to Flash. See http://www.plupload.com